# Mongo database size inconsistency

Tags: mongodb, gridfs, mongodump, mongorestore

I use Mongo GridFS and I have a fairly big Mongo database currently dataSize is at 89GB when I use the `db.stats()` command.

When I create a mongo dump the directory size is 86GB in the file system and when I restore the database on another machine, and run `db.stats()` I now get 122GB.

Does anyone know what's the reason behind this 33GB rise in dataSize after a dump/restore?

**Edit**
Here's the stats from initial database

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.5
connecting to: imgdb
rs0:PRIMARY> db.stats();
{
        "db" : "imgdb",
        "collections" : 4,
        "objects" : 2549884,
        "avgObjSize" : 37802.88397276111,
        "dataSize" : 96392968996,
        "storageSize" : 363433842080,
        "numExtents" : 207,
        "indexes" : 4,
        "indexSize" : 307245904,
        "fileSize" : 366974337024,
        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
        "dataFileVersion" : {
                "major" : 4,
                "minor" : 5
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

And here is the stats from restored database

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
connecting to: imgdb
dbdb.stats();
{
        "db" : "imgdb",
        "collections" : 4,
        "objects" : 2549924,
        "avgObjSize" : 51781.40103312883,
        "dataSize" : 132038637248,
        "storageSize" : 132281756768,
        "numExtents" : 98,
        "indexes" : 4,
        "indexSize" : 199976784,
        "fileSize" : 135159349248,
        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
        "dataFileVersion" : {
                "major" : 4,
                "minor" : 5
        },
        "extentFreeList" : {
                "num" : 0,
                "totalSize" : 0
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Here are some thoughts for possible causes:

1. For some reason I've got 40 more objects in the restored version!
2. Different mongo versions, could that be the cause of how indexing algorithms have changed?
3. Initial database was in a replicaset
4. Initial database used to be at 320 GB, but I went in and compressed all the images and reduced it to 75GB a while back. That's why storage size on initial database is substantially higher

Comment: And what happens if you dump that 122GB database? Does it give you another 86GB dump? Including the other numbers from `db.stats()` would probably help people explain the numbers. Some reading on [`dbStats`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/dbStats/#dbcmd.dbStats) and the [padding factor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-padding-factor) might be useful as well. The size of a database will never be the size of the data it contains due to indexes, bookkeeping, empty space for growth, ...

Comment: I'm dumping the 122GB db as we speak, I'll have that info shortly

Comment: That should only take a couple seconds, right? I remember when a GB was a lot, now my phone carries several of them in my pocket. Look at the other numbers from `db.stats()` too and the padding factor; my MongoDB DBA skills aren't that great but I suspect that those two things would clear up a lot of the confusion.

Comment: As far as I know the dump is not compressed in anyway, this is a odd one, it should, max, be the size of the old database

Comment: @muistooshort it took a while, around 45 minutes. But at the end my data dump is back at 86GB!

Comment: Did you try [repairDatabase](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/#dbcmd.repairDatabase)? I would assume that a dump won't write fragmented data, but better be sure.

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer no I haven't tried running compact yet, but if the data is restored from a dump there shouldn't be any fragmentation in the first place

Comment: You have more objects in your restore, do you know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB 2.6 uses [Powers of Two Record Allocation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collMod/#powers-of-two-record-allocation) by default.

Prior to loading your data, you can try either changing your mongod [newCollectionsUsePowerOf2Sizes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/parameters/#param.newCollectionsUsePowerOf2Sizes) or `collMod` your collection:

```
db.runCommand( { collMod: "myCollection", usePowerOf2Sizes: false })
```

Comment: Does that apply to GridFS, too? Plus, more than 1/3 seems a bit lot to me.

Comment: Yes, applies to every collection.

Comment: Iirc, chunks have a fixed size of 255k. Would be strange if they added padding to this, wouldn't it?

Comment: I must agree with @MarkusWMahlberg I am unsure if power of 2 sizes is actually used on gridfs since the file chunks collection is not one that is easily updated but this could be right, at the end of the day only a MongoDB dev would probably know, or unless you got an object out and did a bson size on it to see it is double its intended size

Comment: Upon further reading I must also agree with @MarkusWMahlberg that 1/3 of its original size does not fit well with power of 2 sizes, every allocation should be double its insertion

Comment: OK, so think about the last chunk of every file. So if we assume that on average the last chunk is only 1/2 of it's allocation, that would be 128kb per file of padding.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: Chunks created by older drivers were 256KB; this was lowered to 255KB as the powerOf2Sizes will push those 256KB allocations to 512KB. Ref: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13331. The recommended fix for importing historical GridFS documents would be to disable powerOf2Sizes for the `fs.chunks` collection, as per the answer here. Depending on the sizes of the chunks in this GridFS collection (which could be a mix of 256KB and 255KB if the driver was upgraded) there may not be a straight conversion of data size to storage size.

Comment: FYI, I just found another proposed feature in Jira which could be helpful to upvote/watch: [TOOLS-210: Tool to change chunkSize of existing files in gridFS](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-210).